# sensor breaks tf tree in ROS

Tags: ros, gazebo, transforms, urdf

I am currently trying to add sensor(lidar) into my robot. I made base for a sensor, link to which sensor is attached through gazebo reference.

The problem is that adding a  tag for some reason creates another one tf tree, with 2 nodes, where my lidar is attached. Whereas there still exists another tf tree with my robot and sensor base.

If i remove  (in fact removing this tag removes sensor, but still keeps the link to which this sensor is attached) the tree becomes well defined.

I want to know how to fix this and to get the single tf tree.

[image: Here is the tree i want to have()]

[image: Here is the tree i have after adding sensor with gazebo reference]

What i add is the following(taken from livox github):

```
<gazebo reference="${name}">
      <sensor type="ray" name="${name}">
          <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
          <visualize>${visualize}</visualize>
          <update_rate>${update_rate}</update_rate>
          <!-- This ray plgin is only for visualization. -->
          <plugin name="gazebo_ros_laser_controller" filename="liblivox_laser_simulation.so">
        <ray>
          <scan>
          <horizontal>
          <samples>100</samples>
          <resolution>1</resolution>
          <min_angle>${-horizontal_fov/360*M_PI}</min_angle>
          <max_angle>${horizontal_fov/360*M_PI}</max_angle>
          </horizontal>
          <vertical>
          <samples>50</samples>
          <resolution>1</resolution>
          <min_angle>${-vertical_fov/360*M_PI}</min_angle>
          <max_angle>${vertical_fov/360*M_PI}</max_angle>
          </vertical>
          </scan>
          <range>
          <min>${laser_min_range}</min>
          <max>${laser_max_range}</max>
          <resolution>${resolution}</resolution>
          </range>
          <noise>
          <type>gaussian</type>
          <mean>${noise_mean}</mean>
          <stddev>${noise_stddev}</stddev>
          </noise>
        </ray>
            <visualize>${visualize}</visualize>
        <samples>${samples}</samples>
        <downsample>${downsample}</downsample>
        <csv_file_name>package://livox_laser_simulation/scan_mode/avia.csv</csv_file_name>
        <ros_topic>${ros_topic}</ros_topic>
          </plugin>
      </sensor>
    </gazebo>
```

Here is the part of the urdf which connects lidar to trunk link:

```
  <joint name="scan_joint" type="fixed">
    <parent link="trunk"/>
    <child link="livox_base"/>
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.2 0.0 0.1"/>
  </joint>
  <material name="blue_custom">
    <color rgba="0 0 0.8 1"/>
  </material>
  <!-- <xacro:Livox_AVIA name="livox"/>
  <xacro:include filename="/home/ramil/catkin_ws/src/livox_laser_simulation/urdf/standardrobots_oasis300.xacro"/>
  <xacro:link_oasis name="oasis"/> -->
  <gazebo reference="livox">
    <sensor name="livox" type="ray">
      <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
      <visualize>True</visualize>
      <update_rate>10</update_rate>
      <!-- This ray plgin is only for visualization. -->
      <plugin filename="liblivox_laser_simulation.so" name="gazebo_ros_laser_controller">
        <ray>
          <scan>
            <horizontal>
              <samples>100</samples>
              <resolution>1</resolution>
              <min_angle>-0.614355377778</min_angle>
              <max_angle>0.614355377778</max_angle>
            </horizontal>
            <vertical>
              <samples>50</samples>
              <resolution>1</resolution>
              <min_angle>-0.673696522222</min_angle>
              <max_angle>0.673696522222</max_angle>
            </vertical>
          </scan>
          <range>
            <min>0.1</min>
            <max>200.0</max>
            <resolution>0.002</resolution>
          </range>
          <noise>
            <type>gaussian</type>
            <mean>0.0</mean>
            <stddev>0.01</stddev>
          </noise>
        </ray>
        <visualize>True</visualize>
        <samples>24000</samples>
        <downsample>1</downsample>
        <csv_file_name>package://livox_laser_simulation/scan_mode/avia.csv</csv_file_name>
        <ros_topic>scan</ros_topic>
      </plugin>
    </sensor>
  </gazebo>
  <link name="livox_base">
    <inertial>
      <mass value="0.1"/>
      <inertia ixx="0.01" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="0.01" iyz="0" izz="0.01"/>
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.00 0 0.00"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://livox_laser_simulation/meshes/livox_mid40.dae">
          </mesh>
      </geometry>
      <material name="blue_custom"/>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://livox_laser_simulation/meshes/livox_mid40.dae">
          </mesh>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <!-- <xacro:Livox_Mid_gazebo_sensor name="livox" visualize="True"/> -->
  <link name="livox">
    <inertial>
      <mass value="0.1"/>
      <inertia ixx="0.01" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="0.01" iyz="0" izz="0.01"/>
    </inertial>
  </link>
  <joint name="base_to_livox_joint" type="fixed">
    <parent link="livox_base"/>
    <child link="livox"/>
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
  </joint>
```

Comment: First image is a tree which i want to have(single tree), second image is a tree which i have after i add sensor with gazebo reference

Comment: i want to know how to fix this double tf tree into a single one, updated the question

Answer (score 1):

This does not appear to be breaking your tree, but creating an additional detached tree.

The tree will only connect if they share a common ancestor. As pointed out by @Chuck you appear to have two links that have `base` in the name. But since they are not exactly the same the links don't connect to each other.

Looking at your second tree, the first guess is that `a1_gazebo::base` should match the existing `base` link. Whatever you're launching or running should have a parameter to set the base link.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't posted the sensor config that generates the incorrect tf tree, but your bad tf graphic shows `livox` as a child of `a1_gazebo::base` and not just `base`.

What happens if you change the config from `a1_gazebo::base` to `base`?

:EDIT:

Okay, so you posted a partial URDF file, but I didn't see a joint in there, so I was confused as to how your sensor was linked to **anything,** so I went to the GitHub account you mentioned and found [this livox_mid70.xacro file](https://github.com/Livox-SDK/livox_laser_simulation/blob/dffebcbb057d37376ebcc2550cadfa498a8490c8/urdf/livox_mid70.xacro) that has the following joint defined at the bottom:

```
<joint name="${name}_to_${name}_base_joint" type="fixed">
  <parent link="${name}_base"/>
  <child link="${name}"/>
  <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
</joint>
```

The weird thing here is that this parent link is defined as `${name}_base`, but the base frame you're getting in your tf tree is `a1_gazebo::base`.

I would suspect your joint's parent link is incorrectly named, but your URDF snippet doesn't give any joint details, so I can't really comment/troubleshoot beyond this.

Comment: by sensor config do you mean the urdf file?

Comment: @Ramil You said `The problem is that adding a tag for some reason creates another one tf tree` - where are you adding the tag? You haven't shown us what text you're modifying to trigger the tf tree to split.

Comment: i have added the urdf part which breaks the tf tree

Comment: @Ramil - I edited my answer here.

Comment: i have added more info about URDF into my question

Comment: @Ramil - Yeah in looking at your update I can see your "good" tf tree has everything situated the way you want, then your broken image your `livox` frame is somehow disconnected. Are you getting any other errors? Hard to troubleshoot this at a rate of one guess a day lol, but it almost feels like your URDF isn't getting fully parsed or something, like it's barfing on the `gazebo reference` entry and then not processing the joint. Might also be some kind of an issue gazebo is trying to bind your sensor to a link that's not defined yet. Last guess could be a name resolution conflict.

Comment: Please try the following: (1) Move your `<gazebo reference>` entry to the BOTTOM of the file, so you define it AFTER you've defined the `livox` link. (2) Change the name of your scanner. Right now you've got `livox` as a link, `livox` as the gazebo reference, which should bind to that link, but then you've also got `sensor name="livox"`, so try changing to something like `sensor name="livox_lidar"` and see if that gets you anywhere. Do these changes *one at a time* and see if you get any resolution. Good luck!

Comment: I have tried both, but unfortunately it is still the same. I have also found out that when i am running gazebo with gui=false, everything is normal